# PHP send email for Forgot Password

Tags: php, sql, email, forgot-password

So I am building a localhost page, and it contains users, so I created a forgot password page to reset password if they forget, and to update the randomized password into the database.

This is the codes for ForgotPassword, and I use it by validating email and not ID.

```
<h2 style="text-align:center;"> Forgot Password </h2>
<table align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" width="500" height ="180">
<form action="doForgotPassword.php" method="post">
            <tr><td align="right" height="50" width="200">First Name</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="first_name" /></td></tr>

            <tr><td align="right" height="50">Email</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="email" /></td></tr>

            <tr><td colspan="2" align="right"><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></td></tr>

        </table> </form> </td></table>
```

And this is the codes for DoForgotPassword, I managed to change it in the database but not able to email the user.
I am having trouble at this line

```
    <?php
    public function sendMail($email =$_POST['email'] , $id)
```

This is the rest of the codes after it.

```
    {
$to = $email /* separated by comma for another email (useful if you want to keep records(sending to yourself))*/;
$subject = 'INSERT_SUBJECT_HERE';

$bound_text = "----*%$!$%*";
$bound = "--".$bound_text."\r\n";
$bound_last = "--".$bound_text."--\r\n";

$headers = "From: noreply@somewhere.com\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" .
        "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$bound_text\""."\r\n" ;

$message = " you may wish to enable your email program to accept HTML \r\n".
        $bound;

$message .=
'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'."\r\n".
'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit'."\r\n\r\n".
'
```

```
        <font size="3" color="#000000" style="text-decoration:none;font-family:Lato light">
        <div class="info" Style="align:left;">

        <p>information here<!--(im sure you know how to write html ;))--></p>

        <br>

            '. /* <p>Charge:    '.$charge.'    </p> */'
        <br>

            <p>Reference Number: '.$id.'</p>

                        </div>

        </br>
        <p>-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------</p>
        </br>
        <p>( This is an automated message, please do not reply to this message, if you have any queries please contact someone@someemail.com )</p>
        </font>
        </div>
        </body>
    '."\n\n".
                                                                $bound_last;

        $sent = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); // finally sending the email


    }
                $email =$_POST['email'];


        function createRandomPassword() {
        $chars = "ABCDEFGHJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
        $i = 0;
        $pass = '' ;

        while ($i <= 8) {
            $num = mt_rand(0,61);
            $tmp = substr($chars, $num, 1);
            $pass = $pass . $tmp;
            $i++;
        }
        return $pass;
        }

        $pw = createRandomPassword();
        $query = "UPDATE users SET password= SHA1('$pw') WHERE email = '$email' ";
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
          if ($result){
          $query3 = "SELECT * FROM users where email = '$email'";
        $sql = mysqli_query($link, $query3) or die(mysqli_error());  
       $rownum = mysqli_num_rows($sql);

         if(!$rownum  ) {
     echo "We can not find your email in our records";
        }

       }
```

And this is the resulting code

```
     if($result){

         if(isset($_POST['id'])){
           $id = $_POST['id'];

   sendMail($email, $id);

           }
         }
                ?>
```

Comment: Do you actually get a $result?

Comment: Is there an error message?  What indication do you have that there's a problem?  Does the email send but just never reach the user's inbox?

Comment: You should not send the password.. You should send them a link to change the password.

Comment: Yes. The email is sent but did not reach the inbox, I tried even using other mail but to no avail.

Comment: don't need $this-> (for using class structure (im using classes a lot so get confused))other than that it should work ^o), are you setting the `$id`?

Comment: oh remove public from the function name? i haven't come across this error before...

Comment: I set the id at the top of the function? But the error is now still undefined index at line if($result){sendMail ($email, $id); }  everything i left it the same as this post expect for the part public and $this

Comment: i think i understand the problem, what you need is if if(isset($_POST['email'])){$email = $_POST['email']}else{return;} or something along those lines check [this post on another forum](http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/121207-solved-unidentified-index/)

Comment: I changed it as edited, but it is still not sending the email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the function I use for any mail I do on my current application (sensitive info removed), it's pretty easy to figure out what you need to do but the comments provided, should answer some questions,

This function allows for html formatting which should allow you to make it prettyful :D

```
public function sendMail($email, $company, $location, $startAt, $endAt, $date, $userId,$duration)
{
    $to = $email; /* '. ',';  separated by comma for another email (useful if you want to keep records(sending to yourself))*/;
    $subject = 'INSERT_SUBJECT_HERE';

    $bound_text = "----*%$!$%*";
    $bound = "--".$bound_text."\r\n";
    $bound_last = "--".$bound_text."--\r\n";

    $headers = "From: noreply@somewhere.com\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" .
            "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$bound_text\""."\r\n" ;

    $message = " you may wish to enable your email program to accept HTML \r\n".
            $bound;

    $message .=
    'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'."\r\n".
    'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit'."\r\n\r\n".
    '
<!-- here is where you format the email to what you need, using html you can use whatever style you want (including the use of images)-->
            <BODY BGCOLOR="White">
            <body>
            <div Style="align:center;">
            <p>
            <img src="IMAGE_URL" alt= "IMAGE_NAME">
            </p>
            </div>
            </br>
            <div style=" height="40" align="left">

            <font size="3" color="#000000" style="text-decoration:none;font-family:Lato light">
            <div class="info" Style="align:left;">

            <p>information here<!--(im sure you know how to write html ;))--></p>

            <br>

            <p>Location:  '.$location.' <!-- $location is the variable you wish to insert as is $date etc --> </p>

            <p>Date:      '.$date.'      </p>

            <p>Time:      '.$startAt.'   </p>

            <p>Duration:  '.$duration.'  </p>

            <p>Company:   '.$company.'   </p>

                '. /* <p>Charge:    '.$charge.'    </p> */'
            <br>

                <p>Reference Number: '.$userId.'</p>

                            </div>

            </br>
            <p>-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------</p>
            </br>
            <p>( This is an automated message, please do not reply to this message, if you have any queries please contact someone@someemail.com )</p>
            </font>
            </div>
            </body>
        '."\n\n".
                                                                    $bound_last;

    $sent = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); // finally sending the email


}
```

This should definitely work (as long as you replace INSERT_... etc), other than that I can't see anything wrong with your code immediately, only thing i can really recommend Is checking your applications error logs, it should give you an indication if anything is wrong.

Else check your php ini file to see if sendmail is activated :)

Regards Steve.

--------- edit ---------

so your new code should be along the lines of;

```
<?php
    $email =$_POST['email'];

    public function sendMail($email, $userId)
{
   $to = $email;
$subject = 'Password Reset';

$bound_text = "----*%$!$%*";
$bound = "--".$bound_text."\r\n";
$bound_last = "--".$bound_text."--\r\n";

$headers = "From: noreply@somewhere.com\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" .
        "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$bound_text\""."\r\n" ;

$message = " you may wish to enable your email program to accept HTML \r\n".
        $bound;

    $message .=
  'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'."\r\n".
  'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit'."\r\n\r\n".
  '

        <BODY BGCOLOR="White">
        <body>

        </br>
        <div style=" height="40" align="left">

        <font size="3" color="#000000" style="text-decoration:none;font-family:Lato light">
        <div class="info" Style="align:left;">

        <p>place link here for password reset</p>

         <p>Reference Number: '.$userId.'</p>

                        </div>

        </br>
        <p>-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------</p>
        </br>
        <p>( This is an automated message, please do not reply to this message, if you have any queries please contact someone@someemail.com )</p>
        </font>
        </div>
        </body>
    '."\n\n".
                                                                $bound_last;

$sent = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); // finally sending the email


}


    function createRandomPassword() {
    $chars = "ABCDEFGHJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
    $i = 0;
    $pass = '' ;

    while ($i <= 8) {
        $num = mt_rand(0,61);
        $tmp = substr($chars, $num, 1);
        $pass = $pass . $tmp;
        $i++;
    }
    return $pass;
    }

    $pw = createRandomPassword();
    $query = "UPDATE users SET password= SHA1('$pw') WHERE email = '$email' ";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
if ($result){
$query3 = "SELECT * FROM users where email = '$email'";
$sql = mysqli_query($link, $query3) or die(mysqli_error());  
$rownum = mysqli_num_rows($sql);

if(!$rownum  ) {
   echo "We can not find your email in our records";
    }

    }
   if($result){
   $this->sendMail($email, $userId); /*does it need to be in a class for $this->? or can you call       functions within the php page without?*/
} ?>
```

------ edit ------

ok the function call should be `sendMail($variableOne, $variableTwo)`

if you delete the variables at the start of the sendMail function so it should be `function sendMail($email){/*code*/}` and try that (the email is required to send the mail)

------ edit ------

I have recently remodeled this function to allow for use of Gmail SMTP, If you check out this [Page from RamDev (Check the post by Stephen Penn)](http://raamdev.com/2008/adding-cc-recipients-with-pear-mail/), I explain the steps as well as the function i built, It may help you understand the process of mail through SMTP.

Thanks again,

Steve

Comment: Do I put it inside my if($result) ? Or another function then echo it inside? Sorry I'm quite new to php especially email

Comment: yeh just input the code to anywhere on the php page then within if($result) {$this->sendMail($parameterOne, $parameterTwo,etc)}

Comment: It's suppose to put inside <?php ?> right? But it's having error on the line                                                              public function sendMail($email, $company, $location, $startAt, $endAt, $date, $userId,$duration)

Syntax error

Comment: could you post the error message and the new line of code in an edit?

Comment: Syntax error: unexpected public after inline html

that line is

public function sendMail($email, $id)

Comment: check edit (remember each variable within the brackets needs to be filled so if one is empty it will throw an error) you can get by this by within the function declaring them like this : function sendMail($email = "something@some email.com") then when you make the call anything you put in the first section of the array will overwrite that etc

Comment: I put this inside the function sendMail($email =$_POST['email'])  but still the same? I tried puting the $_POST outside before the function also cannot.

Comment: Could you post the new code in an edit to your original post?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
include "connection.php";
echo "<br>";
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$email = $_POST['email'];
$check = mysql_query("select * from register where email = '$email' ");
$find = mysql_num_rows($check);
if($find)
{
function makepassword($length)
{
$validCharacters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUXYVWZ123456789";
$validCharNumber = strlen($validCharacters);
$result ="";
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) 
{
$index = mt_rand(0, $validCharNumber - 1);
$result .= $validCharacters[$index];
}
return $result;
}
$random_password = makepassword(10);
//echo $password_final = md5($random_password);
//echo "update set pass ='$random_password' where email = '$email'"; exit;
$final_result = mysql_query("update register set pass ='$random_password' where email = '$email' ");
if($final_result)
{
echo "Your Password is:".$random_password;
}
}
else
{
echo  "Email Not Found";
}
}
?>
```